# Confusing inheritance with super keyword in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, superclass

I am confusing with inheritance and super. Here I am wrote the some code, Please see below,

```
class Animal(object):
    """docstring for Animal"""
    __name, __weight, __sound = ["",0,1]
    def __init__(self):
        super(Animal, self).__init__()

    def setName(self, newName):
        self.__name = newName
    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

class Dog(Animal):
    """docstring for Dog"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dog, self).__init__()
    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = "here is "+ name
    def getName(self):
        return self.name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fida = Dog()
    fida.setName('fida')


    def changeObjectName(obj):
       obj.setName("Marcus")

    print fida.getName()
    changeObjectName(fida)
    print fida.getName()
```

Here I am observing two case outputs,

## 1 When I comment the code in Dog class like this,

```
class Dog(Animal):
    """docstring for Dog"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dog, self).__init__()
    # def setName(self, name):
    #   self.name = "here is "+ name
    # def getName(self):
    #   return self.name
```

And I got the output like this:

```
fida
Marcus
```

*From the above output I have observed the methods called from the super class (i.e; Animal)*

## 2 Without comment the code in Dog class like this,

```
class Dog(Animal):
    """docstring for Dog"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dog, self).__init__()
    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = "here is "+ name
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
```

And I got the output like this,

```
here is fida
here is Marcus
```

*From the above output I have observed the methods called from the sub class (i.e; Dog)*

Why `setName` not calling from super class without comment the code in Dog class ?

and

Please explain the code above ?

Comment: What part of this surprises you? You didn't indicate anything you expected to happen differently.

Comment: Sorry @user2357112. I have edited my code.

Comment: What? Are you asking why, if you don't call super(), Python doesn't call super()?

Comment: Are you confused as to why *inherited methods* are not called automatically?

Comment: Even if the super class methods were called first (which they aren't here), why would you expect the results to be any different? It would set `__name` and `name`, then read `__name` and `name` with `name` being the final return value.

Answer (score 1):

**Example 1**

When you use a member object which is not there in the actual object, Python go up the inheritance ladder and look for a matching member. And if one found it will return/execute it depending on the operation performed. If it is not found in any of the parents also, it will fail with an error.

**Example 2**

When you have a method with the same name in both parent and child and if you invoke the method with the child object, the child object will be searched first and if a match found, it will return/execute it depending on the operation performed. Basically the method in child object shadows the one in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

in example #1, you are *not* overriding the default (`Animal`) implementations of `getName` and `setName`.

- so you first `set` the name to "fida", then you `get` the name (stored in `self.__name`) and `print` the name.
- then you do the same with "Marcus"

in example#2, you are overriding the default implementations of `getName` and `setName` with the ones in the `Dog` class.

- calling `setName()` will now set the name to "here is fida" (you are setting `self.name` to `"here is"+name`), and then you `get` the name (stored in `self.name`) and `print` it.
- repeat with "Marcus"

*overriding* a class' member function will just do that: *override* (replace) the function; it will not magically call all parent classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused about what `super()` does and doesn't do.

`super()` will not automatically called inherited methods of a base class if you omit the call to `super()`. It must be used **explicitly**. *Tis is the Python way*.